# I want to upload pdf or doc file from iOS device to PHP. I got the file Path in onActivityResult method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get the owner information of the iOS device. How can I get the information without using any AddressBook API?

Answer (score 0):

**Perhaps ABPerson function ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople might do?**

you have to to compulsory do something like this..

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
{
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
    ...
}
```

Comment: The question states *"without using any AddressBook API"*.

Comment: i understand, but its not possible dear